# How to make a user scan the html of another website

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for me in javascript to enable a user to parse a html page as they would see it.

So imagine a button on my website and if they click on it, I get a javascript string which contains the entire html page of e.g. bbc.co.uk, as that user sees it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary 3rd party websites? No. If you could do that you could read people's bank statements from their online banking, the email from web mail services and so on. This security measure is called [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can read data from co-operating websites via [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (for HTTP requests) and [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) (for frames).